# Expected value calculation.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $E(h,k,i,j)$ , $i \leq h$,$j\leq k$ be the expected number of the common numbers of two independently chosen subsets of a set of $h$ elements and $k$ elements respectively, where the first and second subsets respectively contain $i$ and $j$ elements. How to calculate $E(h,k,i,j)$ for two possible case here $h\leq k$ and $k\leq h$? Here is one example shown in figure [image]. 
In this scenario how can I calculate expected number of overlap or common numbers which are indicated by T,T' in the figure? Here T is chosen from (5*9 = 45) grid and T' is chosen (7*13=91) grid.

Comment: How are the $h$-set and the $k$-set related? If they are disjoint, then the expected number of common elements is $0$. Are we to assume that one set is a subset of the other? For instance, that one set is $\{1,2,\dots,h\}$ and the other is $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$?

Comment: Perhaps it is because it is late, but I do not understand the question. There is a set of $h$ elements, say $H$, and a set $K$ of $k$ elements, which are perhaps disjoint, or perhaps not. We are choosing $i$ from $H$ and $j$ from $K$. Or maybe we are choosing two sets of size $i$ from $H$, and two of size $j$ from $K$. It does not seem entirely clear what the experiment is.

Comment: @bof : you are right. the set h could be subset of k if h ≤ k or other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that $H=\{1,2,\dots,h\}$ and $K=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, and if $i$ elements are chosen (uniformly and without replacement) from $H$ and $j$ elements are chosen (uniformly and without replacement) from $K$, and if $E(h,k,i,j)$ is the expected number of elements common to both samples, then $E(h,k,i,j)=\dfrac{ij\min(h,k)}{hk}=\dfrac{ij}{\max(h,k)}$; this is obtained by adding, for each $n\in\{1,2,\dots,\min(h,k)\}$, the probability that $n$ is chosen in both samples.

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks bof. I have added an image to give clear picture of the problem.